# Bokeh: how to save a file as svg?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to embed a Bokeh plot (from IPython notebook) into my blog as an svg file. Is there currently a way to save the plots as svg's?

I tried to look in the documentation, but it's a little unclear.

Comment: Looks like this feature - saving plots as svg, png, etc. - is scheduled for release any day in Bokeh 0.8.
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!searchin/bokeh/svg/bokeh/biqOu8T23l0/L2yxwHSx3nQJ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting figures from Bokeh as svg or pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026618/exporting-figures-from-bokeh-as-svg-or-pdf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Bokeh, how to save to a png or jpg instead of a html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060173/with-bokeh-how-to-save-to-a-png-or-jpg-instead-of-a-html-file)

Answer (score 6):

This is now possible! From the [doc](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/output/export.html):

```
from bokeh.io import export_svgs

# option 1
plot.output_backend = "svg"

# option 2
export_svgs(plot, filename="plot.svg")
```

Additional dependencies need to be installed. At the time of writing: `selenium` and a web driver (`geckodriver` or Chromium).

Comment: It does not work for me, there is an error:
RuntimeError: To use bokeh.io image export functions you need selenium ('conda install selenium' or 'pip install selenium')

Comment: @Jaja Yes, and did you do what the message was suggesting? I updated the answer to point to the latest version of the doc and the need for additional dependencies (as stated in the doc.)