# Generate high resolution figures with Bokeh?

Tags: svg, plot, bokeh

Is it possible to generate **high resolution PNG** figures or even scalable vector graphics/SVG files with Bokeh? If yes, how?

From what I could see from the [example gallery](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html#gallery), it is only possible to save low resolution PNG files.

Comment: The SVG question has been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24026618/873282).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting figures from Bokeh as svg or pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026618/exporting-figures-from-bokeh-as-svg-or-pdf)

Comment: As already pointed out, the other question specifically asked for svg files. This question is broader with png or svg files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate, but in case is it not deleted:

As of Bokeh `0.12.6`, it is now possible to export PNG and SVG directly from Python code.

Exporting PNGs looks like this

```
export_png(plot, filename="plot.png")
```

And exporting SVGs looks like this

```
plot.output_backend = "svg"
export_svgs(plot, filename="plot.svg")
```

There are some optional dependencies that need to be installed.
You can find more information in the [Exporting Plots section of the User Guide](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html).

Comment: I am also using the same technique but it increases disk bytes in my VM to very high and the VM hangs. Is there any lightweight version or workaround?