# How to save a Bokeh plot as PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, bokeh, reportlab

I'm working with Bokeh a lot and I'm looking for a way to create a PDF from the figure I created.

Is there an option to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with a combination of the three python package `bokeh`, `svglib` and `reportlab` which works perfect for me.

This will include 3 steps:

1. creating a bokeh svg output
2. read in this svg
3. saving this svg as pdf

**Minimal Example**

To show how this could work please see the following example.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import export_svgs
import svglib.svglib as svglib
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF

test_name = 'bokeh_to_pdf_test'

# Example plot p
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="")
p.circle(list(range(1,6)),[2, 5, 8, 2, 7], size=10)
# See comment 1
p.xaxis.axis_label_standoff = 12
p.xaxis.major_label_standoff = 12

# step 1: bokeh save as svg
p.output_backend = "svg"
export_svgs(p, filename = test_name + '.svg')

# see comment 2
svglib.register_font('helvetica', '/home/fonts/Helvetica.ttf')
# step 2: read in svg
svg = svglib.svg2rlg(test_name+".svg")

# step 3: save as pdf
renderPDF.drawToFile(svg, test_name+".pdf")
```

**Comment 1**

There is an extra information used for `axis_label_standoff` and `major_label_standoff` because the ticks of the x-axis are moving without this definition a bit up and this looks not so good.

**Comment 2**

If you get a long list of warnings like

```
Unable to find a suitable font for 'font-family:helvetica'
Unable to find a suitable font for 'font-family:helvetica'
....
Unable to find a suitable font for 'font-family:helvetica'
```

the pdf is still created. This warning appears because the default font in bokeh is named `helvetica`, which is not known by `svglib`. `svglib` looks for this font at a defined place. If this font is not there, the message appears. This means bokeh will use its own default font instead.

To get rid of this message you can register a font in `svglib` like this

```
#                    name in svglib, path to font
svglib.register_font('helvetica'   , f'/{PATH_TO_FONT}/Helvetica.ttf')
```

right before calling `svglib.svg2rlg()`.

**Output**

This code will create the same figure twice, once with the suffix `.svg` and once with the suffix `.pdf`.

The figure looks like this:

[image: example figure]